# 8 vCPU, 32 GB memory, 250 GB SSD server needs 1 to 2 seconds for a query with 12 SUM functions and a JOIN on a table with 80,000 rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I was recommended that I ask my question here at DBA. Sorry, should that be considered "double posting". A bit of information in advance:

I have already made the following settings (my.cnf):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_sort_buffer_size = 2M
join_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 3M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
sort_buffer_size = 4M
```

Also, I now do the calculation before the "GROUP BY". Means, I make the calculation in a `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... GROUP BY ...) t` and then I use JOIN. Now to the actual topic...

---

I have the following 2 tables (`browsers` and `metrics`). `browsers` is a "dimensions table" which stores the name and version of a browser. `metrics` is a "facts table" which holds the `browser_id` and metrics, in conjunction with a date. According to `explain select (...)` no key is used on `metrics` and the primary key is used on `browsers`.

```
--- old query
SELECT browsers.name AS browser_name,
    SUM(visits_count) AS visits_count,
    SUM(clicks_count) AS clicks_count,
    IFNULL((100 / SUM(visits_count)) * SUM(clicks_count), 0) AS ctr,
    SUM(cost_integral) AS cost_integral,
    IFNULL((SUM(cost_integral) / SUM(visits_count)), 0) AS cpv_integral,
    IFNULL((SUM(cost_integral) / SUM(clicks_count)), 0) AS cpc_integral,
    SUM(conversions_count) AS conversions_count,
    IFNULL((100 / SUM(clicks_count)) * conversions_count, 0) AS cvr,
    SUM(revenue_integral) AS revenue_integral,
    IFNULL((SUM(revenue_integral) / SUM(clicks_count)), 0) AS epc_integral,
    (SUM(revenue_integral) - SUM(cost_integral)) AS profit_integral,
    IFNULL((SUM(revenue_integral) - SUM(cost_integral)) / SUM(cost_integral) * 100, 0) AS roi
FROM metrics
JOIN browsers ON browsers.id = browser_id
GROUP BY browsers.name
```

```
--- new query
SELECT browsers.*, `t`.*
FROM (
    SELECT browser_id,
        SUM(visits_count) AS visits_count,
        SUM(clicks_count) AS clicks_count,
        IFNULL((100 / SUM(visits_count)) * SUM(clicks_count), 0) AS ctr,
        SUM(cost_integral) AS cost_integral,
        IFNULL((SUM(cost_integral) / SUM(visits_count)), 0) AS cpv_integral,
        IFNULL((SUM(cost_integral) / SUM(clicks_count)), 0) AS cpc_integral,
        SUM(conversions_count) AS conversions_count,
        IFNULL((100 / SUM(clicks_count)) * SUM(conversions_count), 0) AS cvr,
        SUM(revenue_integral) AS revenue_integral,
        IFNULL((SUM(revenue_integral) / SUM(visits_count)), 0) AS epv_integral,
        IFNULL((SUM(revenue_integral) / SUM(clicks_count)), 0) AS epc_integral,
        (SUM(revenue_integral) - SUM(cost_integral)) AS profit_integral,
        ifnull((SUM(revenue_integral) - SUM(cost_integral)) / SUM(cost_integral) * 100, 0) AS roi
    FROM `metrics`
    GROUP BY `browser_id`
    ) AS `t`
INNER JOIN `browsers` ON `browsers`.`id` = `browser_id`
```

Server:

- 8 vCPU, 32 GB Memory, 250 GB SSD
- MySQL 8

Without all the SUM functions, the time of 900ms is reduced by about 250 to 300ms. Without the `GROUP BY` even down to 1 to 2 digit ms. Unfortunately I need the `GROUP BY`, as well as the number of SUM functions.

What can be the reason that such a server needs between 1 second and 2 seconds to execute the query on a table with only 80,000 rows? According to `explain analyze` the SUM functions need 96% of the time (`actual time=845.038..845.052`) that is needed in total.

```
-- browsers-Table

CREATE TABLE `browsers` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `version` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `browsers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `b_n` (`name`),
  ADD KEY `b_v` (`version`),
  ADD KEY `b_n_v` (`name`,`version`),
  ADD KEY `b_v_n` (`version`,`name`);

ALTER TABLE `browsers`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

```
-- metrics-Table

CREATE TABLE `metrics` (
  `reference_date` date NOT NULL,
  `browser_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `visits_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `cost_integral` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `clicks_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `conversions_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `revenue_integral` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `metrics`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `mu` (`reference_date`,`browser_id`),
  ADD KEY `metrics_browser_id_foreign` (`browser_id`);

ALTER TABLE `metrics`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `metrics_browser_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`browser_id`) REFERENCES `browsers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Even on my localserver, with the same data, I need only ~10ms - so I suspect a faulty setting of the server (according to mysqltuner there are no remarkable suggestions).

---

**Edit #1:**

```
| -> Nested loop inner join  (actual time=182.931..182.937 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on landing_pages  (cost=0.35 rows=1) (actual time=0.016..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Index lookup on t using <auto_key0> (landing_page_id=landing_pages.id)  (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
        -> Materialize  (actual time=182.911..182.912 rows=1 loops=1)
            -> Table scan on <temporary>  (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
                -> Aggregate using temporary table  (actual time=182.830..182.830 rows=1 loops=1)
                    -> Index lookup on metrics using metrics_campaign_id_foreign (campaign_id=1)  (cost=2065.15 rows=18004) (actual time=0.124..44.976 rows=36266 loops=1)
```

---

**Edit #2:**

*Rick James*

> `PRIMARY KEY(browser_id, reference_date),  -- note the swap` - The might let the GROUP BY scan the table in order rather than building a temp table, etc.

```
| -> Nested loop inner join  (actual time=170.319..170.324 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on landing_pages  (cost=0.35 rows=1) (actual time=0.012..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Index lookup on t using <auto_key0> (landing_page_id=landing_pages.id)  (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)
        -> Materialize  (actual time=170.304..170.305 rows=1 loops=1)
            -> Group aggregate: sum(metrics.cost_integral), sum(metrics.cost_integral), sum(metrics.revenue_integral), sum(metrics.cost_integral), sum(metrics.revenue_integral), sum(metrics.clicks_count), sum(metrics.revenue_integral), sum(metrics.visits_count), sum(metrics.revenue_integral),                                         sum(metrics.conversions_count), sum(metrics.clicks_count), sum(metrics.clicks_count), sum(metrics.cost_integral), sum(metrics.visits_count), sum(metrics.cost_integral), sum(metrics.clicks_count), sum(metrics.visits_count), sum(metrics.visits_count), sum(metrics.clicks_count), sum(metrics.cos                                        t_integral), sum(metrics.conversions_count), sum(metrics.revenue_integral)  (actual time=170.283..170.283 rows=1 loops=1)
                -> Filter: ((metrics.campaign_id = 1) and (metrics.reference_date >= DATE'2021-07-22') and (metrics.reference_date <= DATE'2021-07-23'))  (cost=439.27 rows=3807) (actual time=0.127..89.595 rows=76813 loops=1)
                    -> Index scan on metrics using m_lp_rd  (cost=439.27 rows=76135) (actual time=0.125..76.973 rows=76813 loops=1)
```

In fact, the temporary table is now gone. Unfortunately, this did not increase the speed.

```
/* EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON */
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "133.50"
    },
    "nested_loop": [
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "landing_pages",
          "access_type": "ALL",
          "possible_keys": [
            "PRIMARY"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 1,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "0.25",
            "eval_cost": "0.10",
            "prefix_cost": "0.35",
            "data_read_per_join": "1K"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "id",
            "country_id",
            "name",
            "url",
            "is_direct",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "t",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "<auto_key0>"
          ],
          "key": "<auto_key0>",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "landing_page_id"
          ],
          "key_length": "9",
          "ref": [
            "dn_tracker_v2.landing_pages.id"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 380,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 380,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "95.11",
            "eval_cost": "38.04",
            "prefix_cost": "133.50",
            "data_read_per_join": "104K"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "landing_page_id",
            "visits_count",
            "clicks_count",
            "ctr",
            "cost_integral",
            "cpv_integral",
            "cpc_integral",
            "conversions_count",
            "cvr",
            "revenue_integral",
            "epv_integral",
            "epc_integral",
            "profit_integral",
            "roi"
          ],
          "materialized_from_subquery": {
            "using_temporary_table": true,
            "dependent": false,
            "cacheable": true,
            "query_block": {
              "select_id": 2,
              "cost_info": {
                "query_cost": "7859.85"
              },
              "grouping_operation": {
                "using_filesort": false,
                "table": {
                  "table_name": "metrics",
                  "access_type": "index",
                  "possible_keys": [
                    "m_u",
                    "m_ca_rd",
                    "m_lp_rd"
                  ],
                  "key": "m_lp_rd",
                  "used_key_parts": [
                    "landing_page_id",
                    "reference_date"
                  ],
                  "key_length": "12",
                  "rows_examined_per_scan": 76596,
                  "rows_produced_per_join": 38044,
                  "filtered": "5.00",
                  "cost_info": {
                    "read_cost": "4055.40",
                    "eval_cost": "3804.45",
                    "prefix_cost": "7859.85",
                    "data_read_per_join": "5M"
                  },
                  "used_columns": [
                    "id",
                    "reference_date",
                    "campaign_id",
                    "landing_page_id",
                    "visits_count",
                    "cost_integral",
                    "clicks_count",
                    "conversions_count",
                    "revenue_integral"
                  ],
                  "attached_condition": "((`dn_tracker_v2`.`metrics`.`campaign_id` = 1) and (`dn_tracker_v2`.`metrics`.`reference_date` >= DATE'2021-07-22') and (`dn_tracker_v2`.`metrics`.`reference_date` <= DATE'2021-07-23'))"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the query plans. What else is running on that server?

Comment: @mustaccio I've added `explain analyze` and "nginx + php" is running on the server.

Comment: Looks like you need to seriously increase the sort buffer size.

Comment: @mustaccio What does "seriously increase" mean? I've set `innodb_sort_buffer_size = 10M` and it's still the same.

Comment: `landing_pages`?  I don't see that in the query, nor in the list of `CREATE TABLEs`.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's focus on the speed of the temp table `t`.  After that, we can worry about `browser.name`.  (And why `t` needed to be materialized and auto-key'd.)

Probably

```
UNIQUE KEY `mu` (`reference_date`,`browser_id`)
```

was promoted to be the `PRIMARY KEY`, but I don't know for sure.  However, for this type of data, I usually find it optimal to have *only*

```
PRIMARY KEY(browser_id, reference_date),  -- note the swap
INDEX(reference_date)   -- if any queries would benefit from this
```

The *might* let the `GROUP BY` scan the table in order rather than building a temp table, etc.

Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`; it is more verbose, but includes some extra info.

Assuming the 80K will continue to grow, you may want an even better way to speed up the query.  Build and maintain a [*Summary Table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) and use it for generating the output.

Meanwhile, there are 2 redundant keys in `browser`.  Follow the rule that, if you have `INDEX(a,b)`, you don't also need `INDEX(a)`.  So, drop b_n and b_v.

Comment: Hi Rick. Thank you very much for your time! I have edited my post. Indeed, the temporary table has disappeared. Unfortunately, it didn't change anything in terms of speed. Regarding "Summary Tables". From that point of view, this is already a Summary Table, apart from the fact that it is permanently changing/can change. I have removed the 2 redundant keys. Also thanks for the tip!

Comment: @0x7357 - Please elaborate on how the Summary Table "can change".  I realize that there are such situations and that they tend to add complexity.

Comment: Hi @Rick James. I tried to contact you on Linkedin (forgive me if this is unusual). I would be happy to explain my situation in more detail and even with an invoice from you if necessary.

Comment: @0x7357 - mysql at rjweb dot org .